# Save() multiple records in 1 PUT request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model favorite. In the UI it is possible to drag and reorder these favortes.

When updating the order, i want to save this to the API. Is it possible to save multiple favorites by sending 1 request to the API? By default 1 request per favorite is send on favorite.save().

What I want is 1 PUT request formated something like this:

```
// PUT /api/users/1/favorites
// or 
// PUT /api/favorites

{
  "favorites": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "order": 1
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "order": 2
    }, {
      "id": 12,
      "order": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I would use `embedded: always` on the `favorites` property of the `user` model, then `PUT` the entire `user` model with the updated favorites. Of course, your server will have to be equipped to handle this form of payload.

Comment: Adding `embedded: always` does not send  the favorites when updateing the user record. Also, I am wondering if there is a way to just send multiple favorites to the an endpoint like PUT -> /api/favorites/

Comment: Assuming `favorites` is a `hasMany` on `user`, then `embedded: always` should always send the favorites. What makes you think it is not? Anyway, PUT is an update to a single object, in terms of both the behavior of Ember Data, and the typical HTTP semantics of the PUT method. You can write anything you want, including your own custom endpoint, and your own mechanisms for batching changes and sending them off all at once via ajax to your new endpoint, but Ember Data is not going to provide any help in this regard.

Answer (score -3):

Hi i dont know which technology you are using. if you are using java then you can do something like below.

take a ArrayList which holds the map.

Map itemMap= new HashMap();

ArrayList orderList= new ArrayList();

now add the item to the itemMa, and add the map to the orderList.

now convert the orderList to json.

hope it will help.

Comment: he is using ember-data... on the client (browser) and not Java

Comment: Indeed, I'm using ember-data, thank anyway for trying to help.